# SQL to list both youngest and oldest child

Tags: sql

Is there a better way to list the age (a new function column) of the children and output 2 results i.e. youngest and oldest children?

I tried:

```
SELECT Name, DOB,
DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM Children
WHERE DOB = (SELECT MIN(DOB) FROM Children) OR
DOB = (SELECT MAX(DOB) FROM Children)
```

It seems to be working but I'm not sure if this is the right way or is there a better way for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd need to look at some execution plans; but logically the where clause is going to have to execute on every row not just once but twice due to the or.  So the larger the dataset the longer yours would likely take.  However if you have an index on DOB, I'm not sure how your's could be improved.
So we would want to look at ways to posisbly replace the OR, or somehow eliminate the row by row eval of the where.

So.. if an index exists on DOB... you'll likely get amazing performance from what you have already.

However if no index exists... Other options to consider:

Use a join with an OR I think the join is going to add too much overhead though to be of value especially with the OR

```
SELECT Name, DOB, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM Children
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(DOB) y, Max(DOB) z FROM children) a
 on a.y=dob 
 or a.z=dob
```

if your RDBMS supports CTE... but does the the union and cte and join off set the cost of the where clause and OR? advantage is the select is done once for the CTE and we eliminate an or.

```
with CTE as (SELECT min(DOB) y FROM children UNION Select Max(DOB) z FROM children)
SELECT Name, DOB, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM Children
INNER JOIN CTE 
 on CTE.y = DOB
```

or if you don't have a CTE a subquery make work. this eliminates the OR.. but causes the sub select to occur on each row.

```
    SELECT Name, DOB, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) AS Age
    FROM Children
    WHERE DOB in (SELECT min(DOB) y FROM children UNION Select Max(DOB) z FROM children)
```

or possibly using an exists - avoids the OR which may be slower, but adds subqueries which add time.  Not sure if the benefits of eliminating the OR are offset by the UNION and subselects.

```
SELECT Name, DOB, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM Children 
where exists (SELECT 1 FROM 
               (SELECT min(DOB) y FROM children UNION 
                SELECT Max(DOB) y FROM children) B 
              on B.Y = Children.DOB)
```

So long story short:

you'd have to test to verify but with an index your solution is likely the cleanest and most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You have two subqueries here, which will probably require a separate pass through the data for each (although an index could help).  You can also do:

```
SELECT Name, DOB, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, GETDATE()) AS Age
FROM Children c JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(DOB) as mindob, MAX(DOB) as MAX(dob)
      FROM Children
     ) cm
     ON c.DOB = mindob or c.DOB = maxdob;
```

This does the calculations in one pass through the data.